# How to hide/show "Key Bar" in Activity?

Tags: android

I have an tablet Eee Pad Transformer of ASUS.

Its Home key, Back key, Menu key is inside touchscreen.

I want to hide or show that "Key Bar" in the activity by using code.

Is there any way to do this?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, no. The system bar that is part of Android 3.x is a permanent fixture, to allow users to escape your app. You can move it to "lights-out" mode if you are concerned that it might be visually distracting -- you do that by calling `setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN)` on some `View`, just like you might use to hide the status bar dynamically on Android 1.x and 2.x.